# How to compute the mean based on a grouping of k nearest neighbours?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
df = 
Hour    Production 
12         45
15         50
18         89
21         56

12         49
16         55
18         23
21         44

12         33
15         95
17         76
22         89
25         97
```

I want to group by hour an then take the mean of the production, however, I want to groupie in such a way that a group can occupy -/+ 1 hour. In other words, the output should have the mean of the production at the 12th hour of the three groups, the mean of the production at 15th and 16th hours,  the mean of the production at 17th and 18th hours, the mean of the production at 21th and 22th hours, and lastly just the 25th hour

Is there a better way of doing it other than creating clusters of the hours and then grouping by the clusters?

Answer (score 1):

Since your groups are not evenly spaced define your bin edges and use `pd.cut` to group on those bins.

```
import pandas as pd

bins = [12, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 26]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.Hour, bins, right=False)).Production.mean()
```

Output:

```
Hour
[12, 15)    42.333333
[15, 17)    66.666667
[17, 19)    62.666667
[19, 21)          NaN
[21, 23)    63.000000
[23, 25)          NaN
[25, 26)    97.000000
Name: Production, dtype: float64
```